# JDBC and pgbouncer can they work with createStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, pgbouncer

I have learned that JDBC `PreparedStatement` and PGBouncer can not work together because `PreparedStatement` uses session pooling and is pre-compiled and PGbouncer uses transactional level pooling.

My question is can `createStatement` be used with PGBouncer since it is not pre-compiled? and if not can someone point me to another Java api that can connect to the database and can use PGbouncer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PgBouncer FAQ](https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html) states that while it does not support `PreparedStatement`s to be pooled, you can disable them by adding parameter `prepareThreshold=0` into the JDBC connect URL.

This way you keep the benefits of `PreparedStatement` for other databases you might connect to in the future but still have a working connection through PgBouncer.